# Sanctuary js execute 2 steps of pipe with condition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sanctuary

I have a `S.pipe` for upload and manipulate incoming request file

```
S.pipe([
    getRequestFile,
    S.chain(saveTemporary),
    S.chain(checkIfIsImage),
    S.chain(addWatermarkToImage),   // only execute on image
    S.chain(copyImageToPublicPath), // only execute on image
    S.chain(copyFileToPath),
    S.chain(formatResponse),
]);
```

There are 2 specific steps `addWatermarkToImage` and `copyImageToPublicPath` that should only execute for image files.

I know I can return `Left` from `checkIfIsImage` if the file is not an image but by doing that `copyFileToPath` and `formatResponse` are also ignored.

I want to ignore just `addWatermarkToImage` and `copyImageToPublicPath` if the file is not image

How can I do that?

Comment: Just determine the condition outside the pipeline and provide a distinct pipeline for each branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is to use a function such as `x => p (x) ? f (x) : g (x)`. `g` could be a trivial function such as `S.I` or `S.Right`.

In your case the code would resemble the following:

```
S.pipe ([
  getRequestFile,
  S.chain (saveTemporary),
  S.chain (file => file.type === 'image' ?
                   S.chain (copyImageToPublicPath)
                           (addWatermarkToImage (file)) :
                   S.Right (file)),
  S.chain (copyFileToPath),
  S.chain (formatResponse),
])
```

Note that it's necessary to return `S.Right (file)` rather than `file` in the non-image case.

Comment: Thank your for helping me. I have another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697289/execute-fluture-task-in-middle-of-sanctuary-pipe . I think you can help me with that too. Please read my question and help me if you can.