# Execute Fluture task in middle of Sanctuary pipe

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sanctuary, fluture

I have a pipe like this:

```
S.pipe([
    getRequestFile,                  // not async
    S.chain(saveTemporary),          // not async
    S.chain(copyImageToPublicPath),  // async
    S.chain(copyFileToPath),         // async
    S.chain(someLoggingFunction),    // not async
    S.chain(sendResponse),           // not async
]);
```

There are 2 async functions in middle of this pipe.
I want to `await` for `copyImageToPublicPath` and then `await` for `copyFileToPath` and then continue the normal flow

After some search I found that there is `Future.tryP` function for doing `async` but how can I use `Fluture` in middle of this pipe?

Answer (score 9):

It's a matter of lining up the types.

Let's make up some type definitions to use in an example:

```
foo :: String -> String
bar :: String -> Future Error String
baz :: String -> Array String
```

Now, let create our program step by step…

```
//    program :: a -> a
const program = S.pipe ([
]);
```

```
//    program :: String -> String
const program = S.pipe ([
  foo,               // :: String
]);
```

```
//    program :: String -> Future Error String
const program = S.pipe ([
  foo,               // :: String
  bar,               // :: Future Error String
]);
```

```
//    program :: String -> Future Error (Array String)
const program = S.pipe ([
  foo,               // :: String
  bar,               // :: Future Error String
  S.map (baz),       // :: Future Error (Array String)
]);
```

To operate on the `b` inside a `Future a b` value we use either `S.map` or `S.chain`.

`S.map` can lead to unwanted nesting:

```
fut :: Future Error String

quux :: String -> Future Error Number

S.map (quux) (fut) :: Future Error (Future Error Number)
```

We could use `S.chain` to avoid this nesting:

```
fut :: Future Error String

quux :: String -> Future Error Number

S.chain (quux) (fut) :: Future Error Number
```

It may be helpful to think of `S.map` adding to some computation an operation that cannot fail, whereas `S.chain` adds a computation that *can* fail.